# wordpress site page not loading correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am a noob to wordpress and not sure how to properly formulate my question, so I added a screenshot of the problem. When I navigate to the site below page is visible. It seems all Css and content is not being loaded properly.
[image]

When I click on one of the links the page loads correctly. The site does not have a valid SSL certificate atm and chrome does complain about that, but I never had it before that something like this happens.It doesn't seem to be a browser issue since I tried it on several different browsers.

I also cleaned up the .htaccess file to its default values. I have no idea where to start looking for a solution, any input would be great!

Comment: Did you check if the css files needed are loaded properly?

Comment: @user9741470 that indeed seems to be the problem. In the console there is error  SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is not defined and I do not see any css or js files. any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: Ok, I suppose that you have created your template from the scratch. In this case you need to register the scripts otherwise wordpress will not load them. I will post an answer with a possible solution that you can try to solve the problem.

Comment: @user9741470 I am using ultima theme should that be of any use

Comment: It could also be a wrong url in the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings.

Comment: @DaniëlVisser I don't think it's related to the wp address url, usually this error is related to the resources loading

Comment: If it's the wrong url in settings css and js links will break, i have experienced this many times on a local server.

Comment: not sure why, but when unchecking "
Enable automatic redirection to the "HTTPS" " on the admin panel the page loads correctly... .

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, here is a possible fix to your problem. Put the code inside your `functions.php` file.
I'm not experienced using this CMS, but your problem seems to be related to the css and js resources loading. 
[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) there are some useful resource where you can find more info on how to handle your custom scripts in wordpress.

```
<?php

function init_res(){
  // the wp_enqueue_style() function is used to load all the custom css files
  wp_enqueue_style('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri().'/your/script/path/file.css');
  // the wp_enqueue_script() function is used to load all the custom js files
  wp_enqueue_script('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri().'/your/script/path/file.js', array('jquery') );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_res');

?>
```

Note that with the javascript files, the `wp_enqueue_script()` function will take the `array('jquery')` param, this will tell to wordpress that the loaded script has the jquery dependency.